# Diagonal of a 3D array

Tags: r, multidimensional-array

How can one extract the "diagonal" from three-dimensional array in R?  For a matrix (2D array) one can use the `diag(...)` function.  In a similar way, given an N x N x M array, a natural operation is to convert it into an N x M matrix by taking the diagonal from each N x N slice and returning it as a matrix.

It's easy to do this using a loop, but that is not idiomatic R and is slow.  Another possibility is to use slightly complex indexing (see my own answer to this question) but it is a bit hard to read.  What other alternatives are there?  Is there a standard R way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an array and fill it by some values:

```
> a=array(0,c(10,10,5))
> for (i in 1:10) for (j in 1:10) for (k in 1:5) a[i,j,k]=100*i+10*j+k-111
```

Run the `apply` function:

```
> apply(a,3,diag)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    0    1    2    3    4
 [2,]  110  111  112  113  114
 [3,]  220  221  222  223  224
 [4,]  330  331  332  333  334
 [5,]  440  441  442  443  444
 [6,]  550  551  552  553  554
 [7,]  660  661  662  663  664
 [8,]  770  771  772  773  774
 [9,]  880  881  882  883  884
[10,]  990  991  992  993  994
```

Answer (score 3):

Various diagonals:

```
A = array(1:12, c(2, 2, 3))

apply(A, 1, diag)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    2
#[2,]    7    8
apply(A, 2, diag)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    3
#[2,]    6    8
apply(A, 3, diag)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    5    9
#[2,]    4    8   12
```

Answer (score 3):

Although I'm not enamored of the term "3d.diagonal" for this result, it can be achieved with this simple function (up to identity modulo transpose):

```
arr <- array(1:27,c(3,3,3)  )
apply(arr, 3, function(x) x[row(x)==col(x)] )
# returns same value as diag.3d (arr)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1   10   19
[2,]    5   14   23
[3,]    9   18   27
```

I think a "real diagonal" would be `arr[ cbind(1:3,1:3,1:3) ]`

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is to use indexing, where the indices are a matrix with three columns.  For example:

```
diag.3d <- function(A) {
  # Expect a N x N x M array

  stopifnot(length(dim(A)) == 3)
  n <- nrow(A)
  stopifnot(n == ncol(A))
  m <- dim(A)[3]

  IXS <- cbind(1:n, 1:n, rep(1:m, each = n))
  cn <- colnames(A)
  rn <- dimnames(A)[[3]]
  matrix(A[IXS], ncol = n, byrow = T, dimnames = list(rn, cn))
}
```

Although indices (in variable `IXS`) seem hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is subseting the 3 dimensions array with a 2 dimensions matrix:

```
a <- array(1:100,dim = c(5,5,4))
ref <- cbind(1:5,1:5,rep(1:4,each= 5))
a[ref]
```

Output is a vector instead of a matrix. On my computer it is more efficient than `apply()` and you can also fill the diagonal values.